# Weird issue in Windows 10 Frame.GoBack() method?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I am working on Windows 10 and I am using Hardware buttons for navigating back on all pages but in some case when an operation is completed. I am using `this.Frame.GoBack()` to navigate back to the previous page. But when I navigate back using this method, then when I click on hardware back button first time nothing happens. When I click the second time it works. This happens only when `this.Frame.GoBack()` is used.

**Sample code for Page 1**

```
private void AddNotePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
        {
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
        else
        {
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e1) =>
            {
                if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
                    this.Frame.GoBack();
            };
        }
    }

     protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }

    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BackPressed");
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

**Sample code for Page 2**

```
 private void AddNotePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
        {
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
        else
        {
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
            SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e1) =>
            {
                if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
                    this.Frame.GoBack();
            };
        }
 }

 protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatingFrom(e);
        Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }

    private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BackPressed");
        if (Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            Frame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

     private async void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // calling web service and when I get result=1 from it. I navigate  back
         this.Frame.GoBack();
    }
```

Please, can someone suggest why I am facing this issue?

Comment: Did you try debugging? Was `Frame.CanGoBack=true` first time?

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging but it's not firing `HardwareButtons_BackPressed` event when I click back button first time. When I click the second time it fires.

Comment: So may be HardwareButtons_BackPressed  was not registered when you press back button for the first time. Where are you Registering HardwareButtons_BackPressed? Remember its App wide event. You might have unregistered in some other pages,and came back to page2. I can see you are unregistering  in OnNavigatingFrom.

Comment: Yes, as I am using BlankPage template, I am doing that,because if I don't do that then it is causing weird behaviour.

Comment: So where are you registering it?

Comment: loaded event in both pages

Comment: Can you send me source code link or something?So that i can debug and see

Comment: The code is same that I have added here. Just there is extra code like UI changes etc and in Page 2 just web service call. Some data are private else I would sent you code.

Comment: Register in OnnavigatedTo method instead of in Loaded event

Comment: Still same result not working

Comment: I tried your code. Its working fine for me

Comment: ok not sure why it is not working for me :-(

Comment: try this with 3 pages then you will able to check properly. Navigate from Page 1 ->Page 2 then Page 2-> Page 3 and from Page 3 use `this.Frame.GoBack()`.

Comment: In page 3 are you telling not to use backpressed event?

Comment: yes right in page 3.

Comment: Please give more details. When should i use `this.Frame.GoBack()`? On back pressed event right?

Comment: check the page 2 code. I have used it in AppBarButton also. Try that on page 3. So when you click on AppBarButton it will Navigate back to Page 2, after that press hardware key of emulator and check.

Comment: i tried what you have suggested, its working. check your code properly. you might have missed something small.

Comment: Can you add your code in answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Page1.xaml   
 <Page
        x:Class="test1.BlankPage1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:test1"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <SplitView x:Name="testSplitView" PaneBackground="White" PanePlacement="Right" OpenPaneLength="200">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <Button Content="goto page 2" Click="Button_Click"/>
        </SplitView.Pane>

        <SplitView.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton"
                            FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
                            Content="&#xE700;"
                            Width="50"
                            Height="50" 
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Grid.Row="0"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            Click="HamburgerButton_Click"/>

                <Button Content="Don't click Just added for testing" Click="Button_Click"
                        Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </SplitView.Content>

    </SplitView>

</Grid>
    </Page>

Page1.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class BlankPage1: Page
    {
        public BlankPage1()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += BlankPage1_Loaded;
        }

        private void BlankPage1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
            }
            else
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e1) =>
                {
                    if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
                        this.Frame.GoBack();
                };
            }

        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                Frame.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.testSplitView.IsPaneOpen)
                this.testSplitView.IsPaneOpen = false;
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage2));
        }

         private void HamburgerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.testSplitView.IsPaneOpen = true;
    }
    }
page2.xaml

<Page
    x:Class="test1.BlankPage2"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="goto page3" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
page2.xaml.cs

  public sealed partial class BlankPage2 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage2()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += BlankPage2_Loaded;
        }
        private void BlankPage2_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
            }
            else
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e1) =>
                {
                    if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
                        this.Frame.GoBack();
                };
            }
        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, Windows.Phone.UI.Input.BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                Frame.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage3));
        }
}
page3.xaml
<Page
    x:Class="test1.BlankPage3"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Button Content="goback to page2" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>

page3.xaml.cs
 public sealed partial class BlankPage3 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage3()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += BlankPage3_Loaded;
        }

        private void BlankPage3_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons"))
            {
                Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
            }
            else
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e1) =>
                {
                    if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
                        this.Frame.GoBack();
                };
            }

        }
        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
        }
        private void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
                Frame.GoBack();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Frame.CanGoBack)
            {
               Frame.GoBack();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am doing same thing not sure , why it is not working for me

Comment: Check whether loaded event is called and backpressed is registered before pressing back button.

Comment: I am showing one MessageDialog in that Button_Click event of 3rd page to show successful message. Will that causing any issue?

Comment: I checked it is calling loaded event also and backpressed event is registered.

Comment: I've no idea. MessageDialog wont cause that issue.

Comment: Did you checked in Mobile Emulator?

Comment: Hi, I am able to replicate the exact issue. In your page one, I will edit the code in your answer. Click on hamburger menu then click on go to page 2 button then try. you will get the issue.

Comment: Done. Also I found the solution. Can you try that also and let me know if I am correct?

Comment: Yes,i guess its correct,splitview pane open causing the problem.

Comment: Ok so as a solution I close the Pane before navigating.